# Unable to convert List to Map in Java when the List is returned via For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I am currently facing once scenario, where i want to convert a list to a Map.The list is returned via for loop, and partitioned, say the list is returned as:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6] , and i have partitioned in the format of:
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

I want to convert [1,2,3]and[4,5,6] to `Map<Key,Value>` pair, wherein i will pass the key, and the values would be [1,2,3]and[4,5,6].
eg for the given code below:

```
List<List<Object>> subSets = ListUtils.partition(ls, 3);
for(int i=0;i<subSets.size();i++) {
   System.out.println(subSets.get(i));
```

The output I am getting is:

```
no of rows:3
[test1, test2, 8]
[qa1, qa2, 9]
```

Now I want to pass this to a Map in the loop, such that it takes both the list, in the format:

```
map.put("firstname",test1);
map.put("lastname",test2);
map.put("subjectid",8);
```

The map format should be `Map<String,Object>` as the last value I am passing is an Integer.
Later, i want to pass this map to a Json request, such that i can do a POST request.

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject(map);
System.out.println(request);
System.out.println(request.toJSONString()); //to prevent serialization error

            // so we have our body created, so we have to test this
            //for post we have 201

            given().
            header("Content-Type","application/json")
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON).accept(ContentType.JSON).
            body(request.toJSONString())
            .when()
            .post("https://reqres.in/api/users").then()
            .statusCode(201);
```

As of now i am unable to convert the List to a Map , in a way such that each list value is mapped to a key in a map, within the for loop. Please suggest.

The entire code is here below:

```
class ExcelUtils {

    static XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    static XSSFSheet sheet;
    ArrayList<Object> ls = new ArrayList<Object>();
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    public ExcelUtils(String excelPath, String sheetName) throws IOException {

        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelPath);
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);   

    }


    @Test
    public void getRowCount() throws IOException {

        int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        System.out.println("no of rows:" + rowCount);


    }



    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "getRowCount")
    public void getCellData() throws IOException {

        // String s = sheet.getRow(rownum).getCell(colnum).getStringCellValue();
        // System.out.println("cell value:" + s);

        //double i = sheet.getRow(rownum).getCell(colnum).getNumericCellValue();
        //System.out.println("numeric cell value:" + i);

        //data formatter
        DataFormatter format=new DataFormatter();

        // dynamic code
        int rowcount =sheet.getLastRowNum();

        for(int i=1;i<=rowcount;i++) {
            Row r= sheet.getRow(i);
            int cellcount = r.getLastCellNum();

            for(int j=0;j<cellcount;j++) {

                Cell c=r.getCell(j);
                //System.out.println(format.formatCellValue(c));

                ls.add(format.formatCellValue(c));
                //ls.add("\""+format.formatCellValue(c)+"\"");
            }

        }

        List<List<Object>> subSets = ListUtils.partition(ls, 3);

        for(int i=0;i<subSets.size();i++) {

            System.out.println(subSets.get(i));
        }

    }
```

The output of the code is this:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
no of rows:3
[test1, test2, 8]
[qa1, qa2, 9]
```

I need help with the next step.

Comment: How are you initializing your map?

Comment: i want to initialize the map from the values which i am extracting from the list:map.put("firstname",test1);
map.put("lastname",test2);
map.put("subjectid",8);  . I have not initialized my map yet ,so need help on this.

Comment: Actually what is the error you got when insert the value to map?

Comment: Actually i need a way to insert list of values from a for loop to a map, in the format which i have mentioned in the question. There are no errors, i need help with the logic of how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Object> ex = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ex.add("test1");
    ex.add("test2");
    ex.add("8");
    List<Object> ex2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ex2.add("qa1");
    ex2.add("qa2");
    ex2.add("5");
    List<List<Object>> subSets = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    subSets.add(ex);
    subSets.add(ex2);
    List<Object> listOfMap = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Map<String, Object> mapOfSubsetList = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < subSets.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("List at position ::: "+i+subSets.get(i));
        mapOfSubsetList.put("firstname", subSets.get(i).get(0));
        mapOfSubsetList.put("lastname", subSets.get(i).get(1));
        mapOfSubsetList.put("subjectid", subSets.get(i).get(2));
        listOfMap.add(mapOfSubsetList);
    }

    System.out.println("final list of map ::: "+listOfMap);
```

As per what I understood, you will be getting a list of map which will be sent as a JSONArray.  If you still want to send the map as a JSONObject, you would need a key having the list of this map { "finalrersult" : "[{...}]" }

The result of the above program is

```
List at position 0[test1, test2, 8]
List at position 1[qa1, qa2, 5]
final list of map[{firstname=qa1, subjectid=5, lastname=qa2}, {firstname=qa1, subjectid=5, lastname=qa2}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the actual challenge i am facing is, within the for loop, i want to convert list to a map. The values are fetched from the xlsx file are fetched and put into the list. The same list i want to convert it to map within the for loop.

Comment: @user3640657 I think I would be able to provide solution but I am not getting the exact usecase. Can u please give an example because in the code I wrote, I have mapped the list to a map only